# Executing a Task on a Trigger in Java

Tags: java, threadpool

I have a task which needs to executed on a Trigger (like passing a Boolean true for that function when it needs to be executed).

For this any threading mechanism can be used like Thread, TimerTask or ScheduledThreadPool etc. Of these please suggest best possible way and the thread or mechanism used must free up the resources after its task, as the trigger interval is fluctuating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [RxJava](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava), which provides a reactive programming API for processing observable streams of events.  It's based on the [Reactive Extensions for .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx).  Events could be time-based (e.g, `Observable.interval()`); they could come from a collection (`Observable.from(Iterable)`); or you could publish them yourself using a `Subject`.

### Example

```java
//
// NOTE: For brevity, I'm using Java 8 syntax (lambdas and method references).
//

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Main Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

    final CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final Observable<Trade> trades = simulateTrades();

    trades.where(t -> Math.abs(t.quantity) * t.price >= 250000)
          .observeOn(Schedulers.threadPoolForIO())
          .subscribe(
              Main::logLargeTrade,
              e -> { e.printStackTrace(); done.countDown(); },
              done::countDown
          );

    done.await();
    System.out.println("Done!");
}

private static Observable<Trade> simulateTrades() {
    final Random r = new Random();

    return Observable.interval(50L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                     .take(100)
                     .map(
                         t -> new Trade(
                             Instant.now(),
                             "AAPL",
                             (r.nextInt(9) + 1) * 100,
                             500d + r.nextDouble() * 5d
                         )
                     );
}

private static void logLargeTrade(Trade t) {
    System.out.printf(
        "[%d: %s] Large Trade: %d %s @ %f%n",
        Thread.currentThread().getId(),
        t.timestamp.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime(),
        t.quantity,
        t.symbol,
        t.price
    );
}

final static class Trade {
    final Instant timestamp;
    final String symbol;
    final double price;
    final int quantity;

    Trade(Instant time, String symbol, int quantity, double price) {
        this.timestamp = time;
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Here, `trades` is a stream of Trade events.  Our trigger condition matches transactions with a value of at least $250,000, so we use `where()` to include only the trades matching that condition.  We want the trigger action to execute on a thread pool, so we use `observeOn()` to specify a scheduler that uses a thread pool.  `subscribe()` creates--you guessed it--a subscription to the filtered event stream.  This particular overload lets us pass in the `onNext`, `onError`, and `onCompleted` callbacks as lambdas.

The `simulateTrades()` method creates the event stream that we subscribe to.  Normally, these events would come in through a messaging system, or they'd be published by another component elsewhere in the process.  For the sake of the example, I just use a timer interval to post 10 trades per second, and terminate after 100 trades.